# Why are changes made to a shared variable by one thread in Python not visible to other threads?

Tags: python, multithreading

I'm trying to use the same variable in multiple threads, but the variable's value isn't being updated consistently across threads. For instance, when Thread 1 updates the variable to 1, Thread 2 doesn't recognize this change and sees the old value instead.

Here's a simple code example illustrating the problem. When the user presses the 'a' key, the variable 'QUERY' should update and display as follows:

1. Query1: a
2. Query: a

But, the actual output I'm getting is only:

1. Query1: a

Can you help me understand why this is happening and how to fix it?

```py
import getch
import threading

QUERY = ""
EXIT_THREAD = False
def input_thread():
    global EXIT_THREAD
    last_query = ""
    while not EXIT_THREAD:
        if last_query != QUERY:
            last_query = QUERY
            print(f"Query: {QUERY}")

thread = threading.Thread(target=input_thread)
thread.start()
while True:
    char = getch.getch()
    if char == "\n":
        break
    elif char == "\x7f":
        QUERY = QUERY[:-1]
    else:
        QUERY += char
    print(f"Query1: {QUERY}")
# kill input thread
EXIT_THREAD = True
thread.join()
```

Comment: You don't need `global EXIT_THREAD`. You only need `global` for variables that are assigned in the function.

Comment: It works as expected for me on a Mac running 3.11.4.

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 22.04 & python3.

Comment: TLDR; ShadowRanger said that `getch` keeps the GIL locked while awaiting input. That's a huge No No. It's almost always a bad idea 
to keep a mutex locked while waiting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the `getch` module is poorly coded. It doesn't release [the GIL](https://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock) (Global Interpreter Lock) when it blocks waiting for input, so your other thread isn't *allowed* to run. Synchronizing with locks doesn't help much; the GIL is already protecting access to `QUERY`.

The problem is that after each change to `QUERY`, you go back to `getch`, which locks down the GIL. When `getch` returns, enough time has passed that the GIL gets handed off *immediately*, the other thread checks for changes, sees the *last* change and reports it, the main thread eventually gets back control, but generally doesn't do enough to cause another GIL handoff before `getch` locks it down again, and the other thread never gets a chance to run and see the change until `getch` returns next time. This will likely vary across Python releases (the rules for when the GIL is checked have changed from time to time), but it will always be flaky.

The proper solution would be for the `getch` module to release the GIL internally before making a blocking call, but failing that, you can give the other thread some time to run by intentionally blocking in a GIL-releasing manner just before each `getch` call, by importing the `time` module, and adding a sleep to give the other thread time to see the latest change:

```
while True:
    time.sleep(0.001)  # Explicitly releases GIL for a millisecond
    char = getch.getch()
```

That gets the behavior you expect, and while technically subject to race conditions if *other* threads are involved, for just two threads like this it's pretty reliable.

Comment: Shouldn't it give up the GIL during the `if` statements?

Comment: @Barmar: It is giving up the GIL, just not where you want it to (if you run the OP's program, you'll see the other thread produce a line or two of output after later characters are typed, it's just not a reliable interleaving of lines from each thread). The problem is that the GIL is often released *just* after the `getch` returns, before `QUERY` is updated. The other thread runs, doesn't see any changes, the main thread gets back control, changes `QUERY`, and blocks at `getch` before enough time has elapsed for another GIL handoff.

Comment: Note that it doesn't actually check for GIL release in `if`s. The current GIL checks are limited to a handful of OP codes to avoid wasting time for straightforward code that isn't doing anything overly complicated. It checks just *after* function calls (the delay blocking in `getch` almost guarantees it will hand-off just after `getch` returns), just before jumps backwards (loops, not `if`s which jump forwards), when resuming generators, and a couple other esoteric cases that basically ensure it checks often enough, without slowing down most instructions.

Answer (score 0):

Try to synchronize the two threads using **locks**.

```
lock = threading.Lock()

...

def input_thread():
    global EXIT_THREAD
    last_query = ""
    while not EXIT_THREAD:
        with lock:
            if last_query != QUERY:
                last_query = QUERY
                print(f'Query: {QUERY}')

thread = threading.Thread(target=input_thread)
thread.start()

while True:
    char = getch.getch()
    if char == "\n":
        break
    elif char == "\x7f":
        with lock:
            QUERY = QUERY[:-1]
    else:
        with lock:
            QUERY += char
    print(f"Query1: {QUERY}")
```

Comment: Thank you correcting possible problem in my code. But when I tested with this code, I got the same error on Ubuntu 22.04 & python3.

Comment: The locks are irrelevant on any GIL-using Python distro (and given `getch` is a CPython extension module, it will only run on GIL-using Pythons anyway), and only fixing it partially and inconsistently by providing more opportunities for the GIL to be handed off between threads. On CPython, the GIL is already protecting `QUERY` in such a way that the changes will always be observed by other threads; the locks don't hurt much, but neither are they strictly necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using original `getch` implementation, I implemented `getch` to solve this problem.

Here's working code:

```py
import threading
import sys
import termios

def getch():
    fd = sys.stdin.fileno()
    old_settings = termios.tcgetattr(fd)
    term = termios.tcgetattr(fd)
    try:
        term[3] &= ~(termios.ICANON | termios.ECHO | termios.IGNBRK | termios.BRKINT)
        termios.tcsetattr(fd, termios.TCSAFLUSH, term)

        ch = sys.stdin.read(1)
    finally:
        termios.tcsetattr(fd, termios.TCSADRAIN, old_settings)
    return ch

QUERY = ""
EXIT_THREAD = False
def input_thread():
    global EXIT_THREAD
    last_query = ""
    while not EXIT_THREAD:
        if last_query != QUERY:
            last_query = QUERY
            print(f"Query: {QUERY}")

thread = threading.Thread(target=input_thread)
thread.start()
while True:
    char = getch()
    if char == "\n":
        break
    elif char == "\x7f":
        QUERY = QUERY[:-1]
    else:
        QUERY += char
    print(f"Query1: {QUERY}")
# kill input thread
EXIT_THREAD = True
thread.join()
```